# How to generate facebook hash key for distribution apk (for signed apk)?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, plugins

"errorMessage Facebook error: Session was closed and was not closed normally" 
I am using phonegap and I am getting the above error message when trying to run this code: facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["email"],
function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) }) in export signed apk.
But apk file (unsigned or /bin/xyz.apk) runs on emulator and device. What causes this error? I've created a new hash using openSSL, update it in facebook developer app settings of android and phonegap build and still the same error. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you follow Facebook Doc. way to generate Your Hashkey

Comment: Yes I followed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash facebook doc and use the keystore path used to make signed (distribution) app with the password and use openSSL_0.98e.exe but not worked. Can you please tell me where is the problem